# More expanders?

Tags: expander-graphs, co.combinatorics, finite-fields, reference-request

Having received several exhausting answers to [my recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124708/an-expander-graph) about
the expansion properties of a certain graph, I now wonder whether anything is
known on the following graphs of a similar nature:

1) The graph on ${\rm GF}(p)$ with $z$ adjacent to $-z$ and also to $gz$,
where $g$ is a fixed primitive root mod $p$.

2) The graph on ${\rm GF}(2^n)$ with $z$ adjacent to $z+e$ and also to $gz$,
where $e$ is a fixed non-zero element, and $g$ is a generating element of
${\rm GF}(2^n)$.

3) The graph on $({\mathbb Z}/2^n{\mathbb Z})^\times$ (odd residue classes
mod $2^n$) with $z$ adjacent to $z^{-1}$ and also to $z+2$.

Are these (families of) graphs known to be good expanders? Can one
investigate them using Selberg's 3/16-theorem or other "standard" tools
used to study the graph [my original question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124708/an-expander-graph) concerned with?

Comment: My guess is that (1) and (2) are doomed not to expand because they are "too abelian", or "too nilpotent".  So for (1), a set like $\{\pm g^{n} : 0 \le n \le N \}$ for $N$ large (but small compared to $p$) is likely to contradict expansion.

Something similar should work in (2), considering a set of bounded length words on both your generators.  I think this is closely related to [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91657/is-it-known-that-f-p-times-ltimes-f-p-f-p-is-not-a-relative-expander-fam).

(3) has a very different flavour.  It might be related to expansion in $SL_2$.

Comment: @Freddie Manners: concerning the first graph I mentioned - you are absolutely right, pretty stupid of me not to notice this myself. Concerning the second graph - I still don't see any obvious reason for it not to be an expander.

Comment: The second graph has bounded degree and diameter logarithmic in
the number of vertices (because any field element is $e$ times a polynomial
in $g$); isn't that enough to make it an expander?


Comment: @Noam: sorry, do not get it. First, any (non-zero) field element is actually just a power of $g$. Second, I do not see why the diameter being logarithmic implies that the graph is an expander. (To my understanding, it does not - am I missing something? Could you expand? :-) )

Comment: Any field element is $e P(g)$ for some polynomial $P$ of degree $<n$.
Thus it can be reached from $0$ in at most $2n$ steps.  But I'm not sure
whether this implies that the graph is an expander (the reverse direction
is known).


Comment: The union of, say, three cliques with a bridge between any pair of them has a very small diameter, but is not an expander?

Comment: True, but nor is it of bounded degree.  Still, you're basically right:
joining two expanders of the same size with a bridge doesn't yield an expander. Still this should be close...


Comment: On further thought, Freddie Manners is right: neither (1) nor (2)
can be an expander, and (3) should be.  
Details later if nobody posts the proof first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Freddie Manners is right: graphs (1) and (2) are not expanders
for any choice of $g$.
For (1), he already showed this by exhibiting large vertex sets with
$O(1)$ neighbors.  For (2) we prove it below by contructing vectors $v$
orthogonal to the all-$1$ vector for which the Rayleigh quotient
$\langle Av, v \rangle / \langle v, v \rangle$
is within $o(1)$ (indeed $O(1/n)$) of the graph degree,
thus proving that there is no spectral gap.
Graph (3) is probably an expander,
because the maps taking $z$ to $z^{-1}$ and $z+2$
generate a congruence subgroup of index 3 in ${\rm PSL}_2({\bf Z})$
(as Serre notes in the very last section of *A Course in Arithmetic*),
and the graph vertices can be identified with an orbit of cusps of a modular curve
of level $2^n$, so one should be able to use the $3/16$ bound on that curve;
but I'll leave that to the folks who actually know these techniques.

For (2): let $k$ be a finite field of $2^n$ elements, and consider the graph
where each $z$ is adjacent to $gz$ $-$ and thus also to $g^{-1} z$ $-$
and to $z+e$.
Fix a nontrivial homomorphism $\epsilon$ from $(k,+)$ to the group
$\lbrace\pm1\rbrace$; the usual choice is $\epsilon(x) = (-1)^{{\rm Tr}(x)}$.
Then for each $c \in k$ we have a homomorphism
$\epsilon_c: (k,+) \rightarrow \lbrace\pm1\rbrace$ defined by
$\epsilon_c(x) = \epsilon(cx)$,
and these $\epsilon_c$ form an orthonormal basis for the Euclidean space of
real-valued functions on $k$ with inner product
$$
\langle f, g \rangle := \frac1{2^n} \sum_{x\in k} f(x) g(x).
$$
So we're seeking a linear combination of the $\epsilon_c$ with $c \neq 0$
that is almost fixed by the adjacency matrix $A$ in the sense that
$\langle Av, v \rangle / \langle v, v \rangle = 3 - O(1/n)$.

Write $A = A_1+A_2$
where $A_1$ is induced by translation by $e$ 
and $A_2$ is induced by multiplication by $g^{\pm 1}$.
Then for each $c \in k$ we have $A_1 \epsilon_c = \epsilon(ce) \epsilon_c$
and $A_2 \epsilon_c = \epsilon_{gc} + \epsilon_{g^{-1}c}$.
We shall take $v = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \epsilon_{g^i c}$ for some $c\neq 0$,
so $\langle v, v \rangle = n-1$ and $\langle A_2 v, v \rangle = 2n-4$.
We next show that $c$ can be chosen so that $v$
is an eigenvector of $A_1$, corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.
Because $\lbrace c : \epsilon(ce) = +1 \rbrace$ is a
$({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})$-subspace of $k$ of codimension $1$,
the same is true of $\lbrace c : \epsilon(g^i ce) = +1 \rbrace$
for each $i$, so the intersection of these $n-1$ subspaces
has positive dimension.  Choosing nonzero $c$ in this intersection
makes $A_1 v = v$ as claimed.  Then
$$
\langle A v, v \rangle =
\langle A_1 v, v \rangle + \langle A_2 v, v \rangle =
(n-1) + (2n-4) = 3n-5 = (3-O(1/n)) \langle v, v \rangle,
$$
**QED**.

**Exercise**: Adapt this technique to show that the graph on
${\bf Z} / p {\bf Z}$ where each $z$ is connected to
$z \pm 1$ and $g^{\pm 1} z$
is not an expander either for any $g \in ({\bf Z} / p {\bf Z})^*$.
(That's what I first thought graph (1) was when I quickly read the question.)

Comment: The argument for the second graph is really nice, thanks!

Comment: It is my understanding, by the way, that the situation changes significantly, and the argument does not work any longer, if one fixes *two* non-zero elements $e_1$ and $e_2$, and has every $z$ adjacent to both $z+e_1$ and $z+e_2$ (in addition to $g^{\pm1}z$)?

Comment: 
@Seva i) Thanks! ii) Actually it's much the same with two generators,
or any fixed number of generators.  With two generators,
$\epsilon(ce_1) = \epsilon(ce_2) = +1$ cuts out a codimension-$2$
subspace of $k$, so we can still choose $c$ such that $g^i c$ is
in that subspace for $n/2 - O(1)$ consecutive values of $i$, 
again deducing that the spectral gap is $O(1/n)$.